# PHP - Stop empty form submission on submit button

Tags: php, jquery, html, validation, smarty

I have an html page(edituserdetails.html), where I have a form containing 3 textboxes: FirstName, LastName,Email and a submit button. On clicking submit button, I'm validating these 3 textboxes(inside a function "**SaveEdit**"). 
Below is my code:

```
if ($_POST['SaveUserDetails']) {
        $Id = $args[2];
        if(empty($_POST['FirstName']))
        {
            $this->smarty->assign('FirstNameEmpty',"Please enter your firstname!");
            controller::display($this, 'tpl.edituserdetails.html');
        }
        if(empty($_POST['LastName']))
        {
            $this->smarty->assign('LastNameEmpty',"Please enter your lastname!");
            controller::display($this, 'tpl.edituserdetails.html');
        }
        if(empty($_POST['Email']))
        {
    $this->smarty->assign('EmailEmpty',"Email field should not be empty!");
   controller::display($this, 'tpl.edituserdetails.html');
        }`
```

Now, the problem is that the same function loads the textboxes with contents from the database(This code is also inside **SaveEdit**):

```
$x = $args[2];
    $x = mysql_real_escape_string($x);
    $result = db::sql("Select contact_fname,contact_lname,contact_email from billing_buyer where id = '$x'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $this->smarty->assign('FirstName', $row['contact_fname']);
    $this->smarty->assign('LastName', $row['contact_lname']);
    $this->smarty->assign('Email', $row['contact_email']);
```

Due to this, when I click 'Submit' button even with empty textboxes, page refreshes and fills textboxes from database. As a result, my validations aren't working properly. Please help.
Below is my html(I have used Smarty variable $FirstName,$LastName and $Email for dislaying the respective data. $FirstNameEmpty, $LastNameEmpty etc. are the smarty variables containing error messages for validation.

```
<html>  
<div> 
    <form action="" method="post" id="subscriptions" onsubmit="">
<input type="hidden" value="form" name="action">

<div class="form">

<h2><span>Edit User Details</span></h2>
    <div>

<table id="im_list" class="primary_table" border="0" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing=0>

        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td class="bar_style"> <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="{$FirstName}"></td>
            <td><font color="red">{$FirstNameEmpty}</font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td class="bar_style"> <input type="text" name="LastName" value="{$LastName}"></td>
           <td><font color="red">{$LastNameEmpty}</font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contact email</td>
            <td class="bar_style"><input type="text" name="Email" value="{$Email}"></td>
            <td><font color="red">{$EmailEmpty}</font></td>
            <td><font color="red">{$WrongEmailFormat}</font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
         <input id="SaveUserDetails" name="SaveUserDetails" type="submit" value="Save Preferences">
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML? I can't understand very well your question.

Comment: @Kristiyan I've just edited my question to include my html. Please have a look..

Comment: Okey, I think it's good idea to dump $_POST after `if ($_POST['SaveUserDetails']) {`. Just write `print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: @Kristiyan I just left 'LastName' empty and submitted. print_r shows the 'LastName' as empty

Comment: I've already edited my answer with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my below method.  Initialize a flag with false, Inside each failed validation make it true.

Before your select query add a condition to only if there is no validation error.

```
<?php

  function yourFunctionName(){

    if ($_POST['SaveUserDetails']) {
            $Id = $args[2];
            $error = false;
            if(empty($_POST['FirstName']))
            {
                $this->smarty->assign('FirstNameEmpty',"Please enter your firstname!");
                controller::display($this, 'tpl.edituserdetails.html');
                $error = true;
            }
            if(empty($_POST['LastName']))
            {
                $this->smarty->assign('LastNameEmpty',"Please enter your lastname!");
                controller::display($this, 'tpl.edituserdetails.html');
                $error = true;
            }
            if(empty($_POST['Email']))
            {
        $this->smarty->assign('EmailEmpty',"Email field should not be empty!");
       controller::display($this, 'tpl.edituserdetails.html');
              $error = true;
           }
          if(!$error){
             $x = $args[2];
             $x = mysql_real_escape_string($x);
             $result = db::sql("Select contact_fname,contact_lname,contact_email from billing_buyer where id = '$x'");
             $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
             $this->smarty->assign('FirstName', $row['contact_fname']);
             $this->smarty->assign('LastName', $row['contact_lname']);
             $this->smarty->assign('Email', $row['contact_email']);
             }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you have problem with fills. Try to do your select from DB only if form i success submited.
By the way, do update before select.

success submited = all `if` clauses are passed.

Example:

```
if(!empty($_POST['FirstName']) && !empty($_POST['LastName']) && !empty($_POST['Email']) ){

// update 


// And select
$x = $args[2];
    $x = mysql_real_escape_string($x);
    $result = db::sql("Select contact_fname,contact_lname,contact_email from billing_buyer where id = '$x'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $this->smarty->assign('FirstName', $row['contact_fname']);
    $this->smarty->assign('LastName', $row['contact_lname']);
    $this->smarty->assign('Email', $row['contact_email']);
}
```

Comment: There is no security client side solution. It can be done only server side.

Comment: @Pleasure I dont find anywhere he mentioned that looking for client side validation

Comment: @Pleasure Basically I'm looking for a server side one. Client side validation I would have easily done with HTML5

Comment: @RuchirSharma, it is working correctly? Do you understand my idea?